# Excluding a job from the Jenkins Job Queue when a build is in progress

Tags: jenkins

I have a long-running job (10 hours) scheduled to run twice a day (at 11am/11pm).

I generally only want to commence the build at 11am/11pm.

If the previous build fails, I sometimes want to start the next build early (e.g. 9am).

How do I do it?  If I manually kick off the build at 9am, the scheduled build will go into the queue at 11am, and will execute as soon as the first build completes.  I don't want that, if I manually start, I want to skip the scheduled build.

Another way of thinking of it ... I want to ignore a scheduled (or manual) build request if there is a build in progress.

Answer (score 1):

To do what I'm wanting I've added the following into conditional build steps at the start and end of the job, conditional on the Build Cause of UserCause.

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getItem('Test').disable();

jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getItem('Test').enable();
```

Comment: This seems to solve the problem in our setting (of a build-flow job where Groovy DSL is the central build step), too. Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Peter,

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin

Above plugin will be useful for you.kindly go through the documentation.

Comment: Thanks DevD.  I found that plugin, but from what I see there is no condition that indicates there is a build in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Block+queued+job+plugin

It will allow you to block job when last build is in progress.